# Infrastructure - both sync & async interface & implementation?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, code-duplication

When implementing a library/infrastructure, and the user of this API would want to use the code both synchronously & asynchronously, I read that it's not a good idea to mix sync & async (e.g. the sync implementation includes waiting for the async implementation).

So obviously the sync & async implementations should be separated.

Is there an elegant way to avoid code (or more accurately "flow") duplication for sync & async implementations, which would obviously bubble down to the whole call hierarchy?

```
interface IMyInterface 
{
    void Foo();
    Task FooAsync();
}

class MyImplementation1 : IMyInterface
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        OtherMethod1();
        OtherMethod2();
        OtherMethod3();
        OtherMethod4();
    }

    public async Task FooAsync()
    {
        await OtherMethod1Async();
        await OtherMethod2Async();
        await OtherMethod3Async();
        await OtherMethod4Async();
    }

    private void OtherMethod1() { /* may contain other sync calls */ }
    private void OtherMethod2() { /* may contain other sync calls */ }
    private void OtherMethod3() { /* may contain other sync calls */ }
    private void OtherMethod4() { /* may contain other sync calls */ }  

    private async Task OtherMethod1Async() { /* may contain other async calls */ }
    private async Task OtherMethod2Async() { /* may contain other async calls */ }
    private async Task OtherMethod3Async() { /* may contain other async calls */ }
    private async Task OtherMethod4Async() { /* may contain other async calls */ }      
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When implementing a library/infrastructure, and the user of this API would want to use the code both synchronously & asynchronously

Ideally, each API in your library should either be naturally synchronous or naturally asynchronous. I recommend exposing only the most natural API. I.e., if your library needs to do I/O, it could choose to only expose an asynchronous API.

> Is there an elegant way to avoid code (or more accurately "flow") duplication for sync & async implementations, which would obviously bubble down to the whole call hierarchy?

I've not found an ideal solution for this. The closest I've come is the [boolean argument hack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx), where you have asynchronous and synchronous APIs both forward to an internal method that takes a `bool sync` argument. This internal method has an asynchronous signature (returning a `Task`/`Task<T>`), but if `sync` is `true`, it always returns a completed task.

This ends up looking like this:

```
interface IMyInterface 
{
  void Foo();
  Task FooAsync();
}

class MyImplementation1 : IMyInterface
{
  public void Foo() => Foo(sync: true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  public Task FooAsync() => Foo(sync: false);

  private async Task Foo(bool sync)
  {
    // Pass `sync` along to all methods that can be sync or async.
    await OtherMethod1(sync);
    await OtherMethod2(sync);
    await OtherMethod3(sync);
    await OtherMethod4(sync);
  }

  private async Task OtherMethod1(bool sync)
  {
    // When you have to choose sync/async APIs of other classes, then choose based on `sync`.
    if (sync)
      Thread.Sleep(1000); // synchronous placeholder
    else
      await Task.Delay(1000); // asynchronous placeholder
  }
}
```

Comment: If I choose to expose only the async method, so what happens if I have both sync & async contexts which require this API? As I understand it's not recommended to wait for an async implementation from within a sync context (may cause deadlocks).

What's the benefit of the boolean flag? It seems it just unites both implementations under the same method (so the duplicated code would be in the same method instead of in 2 separate methods).

Comment: @Metheny: The `sync` flag determines whether the returned `Task` is already completed. `await` will behave synchronously if its `Task` is already completed. So there's no risk of deadlock; the `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` in this example is only applied to tasks that are already completed. And yes, the point of all of this is just to prevent logic duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your logic, you can still share some logic. But where it differs, it should differ.

You can generate the code using a templating system (like [T4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates)) if it helps.

Comment: The main thing is that it usually differs just in the await+XXXAsync syntax, which seems like a waste.
And I think it's a bit too sensitive to rely on automatic generation.
So I guess there is no way to avoid it really.