# What are the best practices for implementing a Run method from an interface where synchronous and asynchronous methods are possible?

Tags: c#, oop, .net-core

I want to implement an interface that has a Run method:

```
public interface IRunner
{
    bool Run();
}
```

But the issue I am facing is that some Run functions should be synchronous and some should be asynchronous. One solution would be to implement two interfaces:

```
public interface IRunner
{
    bool Run();
}

public interface IRunnerAsync
{
  Task<bool> RunAsync();
}
```

But the issue here is, that if I have, say, a list of objects implementing these interfaces, I will have to always make a check of what type each object is before calling the method, which feels hacky. What would be best practices to implement interfaces like these?

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55830992/5276946

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps just have the async version, and accept that some callers may implement it internally in a synchronous fashion; they can do this locally and just return the `true`/`false` as a wrapped task via `Task.FromResult`, noting that (at least in current frameworks) the runtime will special-case the `bool` case, and avoid allocating multiple tasks internally (the details aren't important). Your consumption code can just `await` an already-completed synchronous result, and everything will keep working. In some *very specific* scenarios (usually in library code), it *may* be beneficial for your consumption code to explicitly test for synchronously-completed results, and optimize away some of the `async` overheads.

In a more general `Task<T>` scenario, where you don't want the synchronous implementations to have to allocate, consider switching to `ValueTask<T>` instead; with that API, synchronous implementations can return a `new ValueTask<TheType>(value)` without allocating, and asynchronous versions can either wrap a `Task<T>`, or can simply declare themselves as `async ValueTask<T> Whatever()` and let the compiler worry about the details. There is also a third way of implementing `ValueTask<T>`, for niche async low-allocation scenarios, but: that's probably overkill here. One caveat with `ValueTask[<T>]`: a value-task should *only be awaited once* (or rather: the outcome should only be retrieved once).